# Locating the yarn logs on the cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I use

```
yarn logs -applicationId "id"
```

to show the logs on the command line, but I need to locate the files on the cluster..I wanted to know where the log saved on the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

The yarn logs commands pulls the logs from HDFS where they are aggregated after the map reduce job completes (assuming logs aggregation is enabled). The location they are stored in is controlled by:

```
yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir
```

Inside that directory on HDFS you should find a sub directory for the user and then the logs inside another sub-directory.